# nodejs pg-pool doesn't seem to be pooling

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, node-pg-pool

I've been trying to get nodejs to pool postgresql connections in my app unsuccessfully. This is an independent test I did:

```
const config = require('../config/project_config.json');
const Pool = require('pg-pool');

var pool = new Pool({
    user: config.DB_USER,
    host: config.DB_HOST,
    database: config.DB_DB,
    password: config.DB_PW,
    port: 5432,
    max: 500,
    min: 200,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 10000
});

for (var i=0; i<100; i++){
    pool.query(
        "SELECT id, email FROM players WHERE email ~ 'ltUser'",
        [],
        (err, res) => {
            if (err !== null && err != undefined){
                console.log(`err: ${err}`);
            }
            else{
                console.log(`num rows: ${res.rows.length}`);
            }
        });
}
```

And the result I get is:

```
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
err: Error: Connection terminated due to connection timeout
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
num rows: 400
```

As you can see, it's throwing connection timeouts, which means that it didn't create the connections when I created the pool. I've tried various combinations of parameters when creating the pool, including having a `keepalive: true`, and none of it seems to make pg-pool actually pool connections. I've also tried pg instead of pg-pool. but got exactly the same results, though I've since found out that it's basically the same code.

If I run it with a longer running query, I can connect to the database in psql and run

```
SELECT datname,usename, ssl, client_addr, count(*
FROM pg_stat_ssl
  JOIN pg_stat_activity
    ON pg_stat_ssl.pid = pg_stat_activity.pid
where usename != 'azure_superuser'
group by datname,usename, ssl, client_addr;
```

And watch the connection count for my IP address go up and then back down again.

Am I doing something wrong or is pg-pool broken?

I'm using nodejs v10.22.1 on an ubuntu xenial server.

Comment: `max: 500` seems far too high. Your code is actually trying to make 100 connections, not pooling anything. I guess the connection timeouts you're seeing are coming from your database, not being configured to take that many clients.

Comment: "*it didn't create the connections when I created the pool*" - that's not how a pool works. The connections are getting created only when clients require them, not when the pool is created.

Comment: The database can handle up to 955 client connections, and is currently only using about 200 of them for other things. It doesn't work if I set the number to 20 either. Exactly the same result.

Comment: Btw [there is no `min` option](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1869) (any more)

Comment: @Bergi the point of pooling is so that connections are not created on the fly, as that takes a lot of resources. In my erlang applications, the app creates connections on startup and checks them out of the pool when it needs them. If it creates connections when it runs the query, that's not pooling.

Comment: It keeps them in the pool after their first use, and discards them after a further `idleTimeoutMillis` without usage. The `pg-pool` is dynamic, not static. It does create new connections when a client is checked out to run a query, if no idle ones are sitting around ready to be used and if the maximum hasn't been hit.

Comment: If it were to pre-establish the connections, what would happen when the timeouts fired as it was doing so?  How would that be different than what you are seeing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that pg-pool is working, just not in the way I expected based on my experience in other programming languages like Java and Erlang. Nodejs doesn't create the connections ahead of time, but when a connection is checked out of the pool.

Based on this the main advantage of pooling in Nodejs is that the programmer doesn't have to handle opening and closing connections, and that connections can be re-used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a certain number of connections to the back end, say 200 ( this is too large a number, likely you want about 64 )

Then you can do this by creating the pool, and then immediately issuing 200 queries, **without releasing the clients**

And then release all 200 clients.

From that point on, if `idleTimeoutMillis === 0`, the pool will forever hold 200 open connections to the DB, which you can use as an initialised pool

```js
var pool = new Pool({
    user: config.DB_USER,
    host: config.DB_HOST,
    database: config.DB_DB,
    password: config.DB_PW,
    port: 5432,
    max: 200,   // set max to 200 connections to the db
    //min: 200, // min is not a configuration option
    idleTimeoutMillis: 0,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 10000
});

// create a list to hold all the "done" functions 
//   that release clients
let releaseClientDoneList = [];

// open 200 clients, without releasing them
for (var i=0; i<200; i++){
  // callback - checkout a client
  pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
      // asyncronously store the "done" function once the client 
      //   has connected to the db
      connectedNewClient(done);
    }
  )
}

let connectedNewClient = function (doneFunction) {
  // store the "done" function in the list
  releaseClientDoneList.push(doneFunction)

  // if the list has 200 "done" functions inside, 
  //   then we know we have initialised all the clients we want
  if (releaseClientDoneList.length >= 200) {
    
    // call all the "done" functions to release all the clients
    for (let doneFunctionReleasesClient of releaseClientDoneList) {
      doneFunctionReleasesClient();
    }

    // now we know there are 200 available, 
    //   initialised db connections in the pool
    databasePoolInitialised();
  }
}

let databasePoolInitialised = function () {
  // ... rest of your application code goes here
}
```